# Can't Find System.ServiceModel Reference for my CLR Project

Tags: c#, .net, reference, clr, sqlclr

I'm trying to add the System.ServiceModel reference on my CLR project. When I click 'Add Reference' on my CLR project, all I see within the window that pops up when I try to do this is the Projects and SQL Server tabs. Under the SQL Server tab there is no System.ServiceModel reference. No matter what framework I target my project to, I do not see the System.ServiceModel reference. What can I do?

Comment: No matter what framework I target my project to (2, 3, 3.5, 4), I do not see the System.ServiceModel reference.

Comment: Are you sure you are not using Client profile ?

Comment: Is your CLR project a C# project? which language is that? not sure why you get only Projects and SQL, no .Net tab?

Comment: Yes, it is a C# project.

Comment: well I guess your Visual studio installation needs to be redone :-)

Comment: I've tried repairing it already...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure you're supposed to have the ability to do this at all, actually. At least, in VS2010 I can't do this, none of my colleagues at work can either. You only see the SQL and Project tabs, and the only time you get the ServiceModel reference in the project's references is when you add a service reference to an actual WCF service.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

http://community.aspnix.com/windows-manuals-tutorials-tos/1867-system-servicemodel-assembly-found.html

> Hi all,
>
> I ran into this issue today for my domain. After some investigation it
>   turned out that eventhough .Net 3.0 was installed on the server, IIS
>   did not seem to find the system.service assembly required to execute
>   WCF or Cardspace code. Running ServiceModelReg.exe on the server (you
>   will have to ask support to do this for you) does the trick.
>
> Here is the full command to run:
>   %WINDOWS%Microsoft.NETFrameworkv3.0Windows Communication
>   FoundationServiceModelReg.exe /i /x
>
> Once this is done, your web application will be able to instanciate
>   objects for the system.servicemodel assembly.

I found this file on my own machine, should do the trick.